# How to write a class which can implement an interface in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I am beginner with the TypeScript. I have below piece of code

```
async function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)
    })
}

async function randomDelay() {
    const randomTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)
    return sleep(randomTime)
}

class ShipmentSearchIndex {
    async updateShipment(id: string, shipmentData: any) {
        const startTime = new Date()
        await randomDelay()
        const endTime = new Date()
        console.log(`update ${id}@${
            startTime.toISOString()
            } finished@${
            endTime.toISOString()
            }`
        )

        return { startTime, endTime }
    }
}

// Implementation needed
interface ShipmentUpdateListenerInterface {
    receiveUpdate(id: string, shipmentData: any)
}
```

I have to write a class which implements the `ShipmentUpdateListenerInterface`. How can I do that in TypeScript?

Comment: @sagar Yes I did that. But unable to get anything. Needed an explained answer.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Answer (score 2):

Make your class implement the interface using implements keyword:

```
class  ShipmentUpdate implements ShipmentUpdateListenerInterface {
    receiveUpdate(id: string, shipmentData: any){
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I check it working using some fiddle or something?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?noImplicitAny=false&target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAtgAcC2FwCqWAJnJADLADOkI0AkuNPEsgN4BQy3yUESwAG4QipSAApgxAFzIaUUAHMANHMy58YACJk4suCACeASgDcHAL4cEAGzhUq3DNjyESZFMBxYbEV2EdnDTcxCEoafAYmWEQUTh5efgghEXcJKVl5JVUqdX8dMD1kAxN4nisLIA